# Use the odd side page layout with book class oneside option in Hebrew document

Tags: book-design, hebrew

I am writing a book in Hebrew. I want the output to be "one-side" meaning that both odd and even pages appear the same.

So I tried the option `oneside` in the document class but it makes the text and layout to appear incorrect.

An image describes it better:

The output I want is the one on the right, but with `oneside` I get the one on the left.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
left=12mm,
top=27.4mm,
textwidth=130mm,
marginparsep=8.2mm,
marginparwidth=49.4mm,
textheight=55\baselineskip,
headheight=\baselineskip,showframe}
%\reversemarginpar

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\chapter{הקדמה}
לורם איפסום \marginpar{טקסט בצד העמוד}דולור סיט אמט
\end{document}
```

Comment: the default for oneside is equal left and right margins. as you are already using geometry you can specify whatever left margin you want you have specified 12mm on the left and a text block of 130mm, you have not specified a paper size so that will default to US Letter paper so the right margin will be 8in less than the text block width - left margin

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So I understand I have specified wrong dimensions, overall. Given that I want `textwidth=130mm, marginparsep=8.2mm, marginparwidth=49.4mm` with `a4paper`, what other keys should I change or add to the geometry set up? `top`, `textheight` and `headheight` are actually irrelevant for this question.

Comment: add a4paper option and then just increas left= to whatever you want

Comment: Thanks. With `left=68mm` it looks ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for oneside is equal left and right margins. As you are already using `geometry` you can specify whatever left margin you want. You have specified 12mm on the left and a text block of 130mm, you have not specified a paper size so that will default to US Letter paper, so the right margin will be 8in less than the text block width - left margin.

Add `a4paper` option and then just increase `left=` to whatever you want, eg `left=68mm`